# NetLogo: Unwrap World in 3D

Tags: netlogo

I have what I think should be a very simple problem. In 2D NetLogo, I can easily "**unwrap**" the world by checking the boxes in the **Configuration** Window. However in 3D, these check boxes are not accessible as they are in a light grey text. Does NetLogo 3D not allow unwrapping? or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/3d.html :

> You'll also notice on the left side of the Model Settings that there are options for wrapping in all three directions, however, they are all checked and grayed out. Topologies are not yet supported in NetLogo 3D, so the world always wraps in all dimensions.

If NetLogo 3D development were still moving forward, this would certainly be one of the highest priority fixes. But NetLogo 3D currently isn't moving forward, and hasn't been for some years, for lack of funding and/or interested open source developers. Know anyone with money or time on their hands?